# Best way to restore a database with FILESTREAM data using C# (SMO)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I am writing a simple C# application that'll allow users restore a databases by selecting path to the db and supplying a new name to the database - my problems are;

1. The restore function still looks for the path where the backup was generated from and fails
2. The database backup contains FILESTREAM data and also fails because I can't seem to account for/or relocate that aswell.

**The code C#**

```
    Restore dbRestore = new Restore();
    BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
    dbRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
    dbRestore.Database = databaseName;

    ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
    Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

    Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    dbRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath + databaseName + ".mdf";
    String logFileLocation = logFilePath + databaseName + "_Log.ldf";
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    DataTable dtFileList = dbRestore.ReadFileList(sqlServer);
    string dbLogicalName = dtFileList.Rows[0][0].ToString();
    string logLogicalName = dtFileList.Rows[1][0].ToString();
    dbRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(dbLogicalName, dataFileLocation));
    dbRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logLogicalName + "_log", logFileLocation));
    dbRestore.ReplaceDatabase = true;

    dbRestore.dbRestore(sqlServer);
    db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
    db.SetOnline();
    sqlServer.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.ToString());

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "This is exception for testing");
}
```

**The ##error**

> Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' in
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Restore
>   failed for Server 'SERVERNAME'.  --->
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An
>   exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Logical file 'DatabaseDemo_4do6_EM_INDEXGROUP_log' is not part of database
>   'NewDatabaseName'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to list the logical file
>   names. RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction
>   action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean
>   catchException)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String
>   sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection
>   sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType, Boolean retry)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server
>   server, StringCollection queries)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv) The
>   program '[14052] OPSAdmin.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

**Question**:

1. How can I do this efficiently and also accounting for the filestream data
2. What are my doing wrong with my 'RelocateFiles' function.

Thank you.!!

Comment: Are there more rows in dtFileList?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Okay, yes there are more rows in dtFileList and when I relocate them aswell, the restore works fine but my  issue is how do I dynamically handle this,  considering some database may have more rows than other in dtFileList? Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define separate variable for holding the Filestream filegroup name.

```cs
String fileStreamFGPhysicalPath = dataFilePath + databaseName;
string fileStreamFGLogicalName;
string dbLogicalName;
string logLogicalName;
```

You need to loop through the datatable to identify filestream logicalName. You can identify it using FileType column.

```cs
 DataTable dtFileList = dbRestore.ReadFileList(sqlServer);

 Foreach(DataRow dr in dtFileList)
{
   switch (dr["Type"])
    {     
     case "D":
      dbLogicalName = dr["LogicalName"].ToString();
      break;
     case "L":
      logLogicalName = dr["LogicalName"].ToString();
      break;
     case "S":
      fileStreamFGLogicalName= dr["LogicalName"].ToString();
      break;
    }
}
```

Now, define relocate file for filestream also.

```cs
dbRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(dbLogicalName, dataFileLocation));
dbRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logLogicalName + "_log", logFileLocation));
dbRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(fileStreamFGLogicalName , fileStreamFGPhysicalPath ));
```

**Note:** I have considered only three files here: data, log, filestream. You could be having multiple data files. So, you need to make the datafile names as arrays and move them accordingly in the Relocatefiles.

Comment: Thank you @venkataraman for your input, that worked. I do have a followup question about your response. How do I dynamically handle this? I updated my code as suggested and it worked for a database with only 3 entries in the DataTable but when I tried a different database with 4 entries, it fails. How do you advise I handle this dynamically when the entries in DataTable for different databases varies? Thanks in advance